Relationships in Odoo?
I'm trying to make a Odoo module to test CRUD functions, I'm trying to use a relationship between 2 PostGreSQL tables that I've already created, first, I used a view to make Odoo contact with the database, but it can only read data, not delete, create or update, so I decided to change to use the real tables instead, but I cannot make it to work, here is what I have:
from odoo import models, fields

class PcClientes(models.Model):
    _name = 'clientes.pc_clientes'
    _description = 'Clientes PC'
    _table = 'pc_clientes'  # Nombre de la tabla en la base de datos
    _auto = False  # No queremos que Odoo cree la tabla automáticamente, ya existe

    # Campos de la tabla pc_clientes
    xempgen_id = fields.Char(string='EmpGen ID', required=True)
    xcliente_id = fields.Char(string='Cliente ID', required=True)
    xcod_postal = fields.Char(string='Código Postal')
    xdomicilio = fields.Char(string='Domicilio')
    xnif = fields.Char(string='NIF')
    xnif_ue = fields.Char(string='NIF UE')
    xnomabrev = fields.Char(string='Nombre Abreviado')
    xnombre = fields.Char(string='Nombre', required=True)
    xpais_id = fields.Char(string='ID País')
    xper_fiscal = fields.Char(string='Período Fiscal')
    xpoblacion = fields.Char(string='Población')
    xprovincia_id = fields.Char(string='ID Provincia')
    xlatitud = fields.Float(string='Latitud')
    xlongitud = fields.Float(string='Longitud')
    trial723 = fields.Char(string='Trial723')

    # Relación con la tabla pl_clientes
    pl_cliente_id = fields.Many2one(
        'clientes.pl_clientes', 
        string="PL Cliente", 
        ondelete='cascade', 
        required=True
    )

class PlClientes(models.Model):
    _name = 'clientes.pl_clientes'
    _description = 'Clientes PL'
    _table = 'pl_clientes'  # Nombre de la tabla en la base de datos
    _auto = False  # No queremos que Odoo cree la tabla automáticamente, ya existe

    # Campos de la tabla pl_clientes
    xcliente_id = fields.Char(string='Cliente ID', required=True)
    xcod_docto = fields.Char(string='Código Documento')
    xcopias_alb = fields.Integer(string='Copias Albarán')
    xcopias_fact = fields.Integer(string='Copias Factura')
    xmodalidad_id = fields.Char(string='ID Modalidad')
    xpor_comision = fields.Float(string='Porcentaje Comisión')
    xreferencia = fields.Char(string='Referencia')
    xrepresentante_id = fields.Char(string='ID Representante')
    xsecpref_id = fields.Char(string='ID SecPref')
    xtipo_fact = fields.Integer(string='Tipo de Factura', required=True)
    xempgen_id = fields.Char(string='EmpGen ID', required=True)
    xempresa_id = fields.Char(string='Empresa ID', required=True)
    xfax = fields.Char(string='Fax')
    xtelefono = fields.Char(string='Teléfono')
    xemail = fields.Char(string='Email')
    xfecha_alta = fields.Datetime(string='Fecha Alta')
    xfecha_baja = fields.Datetime(string='Fecha Baja')
    xinternet = fields.Char(string='Internet')
    xlangage = fields.Integer(string='Lenguaje')
    xlangage_remplace = fields.Integer(string='Lenguaje Reemplazado')
    xcopias_ped = fields.Integer(string='Copias Pedido')
    xcredito = fields.Float(string='Crédito')
    xctacon = fields.Char(string='Cta Con')
    xctamayor = fields.Char(string='Cta Mayor')
    xcyc_activo = fields.Integer(string='Cyc Activo')
    xcyc_poliza = fields.Char(string='Cyc Póliza')
    xdivisa_id = fields.Char(string='ID Divisa')
    xdto_com = fields.Float(string='Dto. Comercial')
    xcoment_albaran = fields.Char(string='Comentario Albarán')
    xcoment_factura = fields.Char(string='Comentario Factura')
    xcoment_pedido = fields.Char(string='Comentario Pedido')
    xcontacto = fields.Char(string='Contacto')
    xagrupa_alb = fields.Integer(string='Agrupa Albarán')
    xalb_valorado = fields.Integer(string='Albarán Valorador')
    xalta_modif = fields.Integer(string='Alta Modificada')
    xcalificacion_id = fields.Char(string='ID Calificación')
    xcargo = fields.Char(string='Cargo')
    xrecibe_facturae = fields.Integer(string='Recibe Facturae')
    xxjuego_id = fields.Char(string='ID Juego')
    p856_tipo_tarifa = fields.Char(string='Tipo Tarifa')
    p856_dto_metraje = fields.Float(string='Dto. Metraje')
    p856_dto_tarifa = fields.Float(string='Dto. Tarifa')
    p856_agen_com_id = fields.Char(string='Agente Com')
    p856_eti_metr_ext = fields.Char(string='Etiqueta Metr Ext')
    p856_observaciones = fields.Char(string='Observaciones')
    p856_cadena = fields.Char(string='Cadena')
    p856_credito_aseg = fields.Float(string='Crédito Asegurado')
    p856_credito_rioma = fields.Float(string='Crédito Rioma')
    p856_crm_id = fields.Char(string='ID CRM')
    p856_modificado = fields.Integer(string='Modificado')
    p856_modificado_r = fields.Integer(string='Modificado R')
    p856_dto_met_max = fields.Float(string='Dto. Metraje Max')
    p856_dto_pie_max = fields.Float(string='Dto. Pie Max')
    p856_entite = fields.Char(string='Entidad')
    p856_pass_crm = fields.Char(string='Pass CRM')
    p856_cerrado = fields.Integer(string='Cerrado')
    p856_supervisor = fields.Char(string='Supervisor')
    p856_tipo_cliente = fields.Integer(string='Tipo Cliente')
    p856_fact_ftp = fields.Integer(string='Fact. FTP')
    p856_backoffice_id = fields.Char(string='ID Backoffice')
    trial726 = fields.Char(string='Trial 726')

    # Relación con la tabla pc_clientes
    pc_cliente_id = fields.Many2one(
        'clientes.pc_clientes', 
        string="PC Cliente", 
        ondelete='cascade', 
        required=True
    )

That's my models.py
    <odoo>
    <data>

      <record id="clientes_list_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">clientes.list.view</field>
        <field name="model">clientes.pc_clientes</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
          <list>
            <field name="xempgen_id"/>
            <field name="xcliente_id"/>
            <field name="xnomabrev"/>
            <field name="xnombre"/>
            <field name="pl_cliente_id.xfax"/>
          </list>
        </field>
      </record>

      <record id="clientes_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">clientes.form.view</field>
        <field name="model">clientes.pc_clientes</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
          <form>
          <group name="Datos indicativos" string="Datos indicativos" class="central">

            <group>
              <field name="xnombre" class="field"/>
            </group>
            <group>
              <field name="xnomabrev" class="field"/>
            </group>
            <group>
              <field name="xreferencia" class="field"/>
            </group>
              <field name="pl_cliente_id.xfax" class="field"/>
            <group/>

            

          </group>
          </form>
        </field>
      </record>

      <record id="clientes_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Clientes</field>
        <field name="res_model">clientes.pc_clientes</field>
        <field name="view_mode">list,form</field>
      </record>

      <menuitem id="menu_root" name="Rioma"/>
      <menuitem id="menu_clientes" name="Clientes" parent="menu_root"/>
      <menuitem id="menu_clientes_list" name="Clientes List"
      parent="menu_clientes" action="clientes_action"/>
      
    </data>
</odoo>

That's my view.
When I run the odoo server, it gives me this error:
Error while validating view near:

            <field name="xnombre"/>
            <field name="pl_cliente_id.xfax"/>
          </list>
Field "pl_cliente_id.xfax" does not exist in model "clientes.pc_clientes"

View error context:
{'file': 'c:\\odoo\\modules\\clientes\\views\\templates.xml',
 'line': 7,
 'name': 'clientes.list.view',
 'view': ir.ui.view(878,),
 'view.model': 'clientes.pc_clientes',
 'view.parent': ir.ui.view(),
 'xmlid': 'clientes_list_view'}

I'm new at Odoo, thank you so much for your help guys

You dont need to specify Database-table using _table

Why there are two model with the exact _name attribute each one is with different list of fields odoo will take only one of them and I think this is why Odoo is not finding the field even that it's declared in the second code because odoo only the first class in your code with only few fields?

When you create a new model, you must also create the security access rules
Usually there's a security folder on each module with the files security.xml and ir.model.access.csv
Regarding your error, the relation field in the end of your list model makes no sense, as it is creating an unresolved relation between each other.
They can't be both a Many2One relation.
Many client_pc have ONE client_pl?
but
Many client_pl have ONE client_pc?
Think like this. You go to a bar that only sells Beer.
A client can drink multiple Beers, but each beer is drunk by a single client.
So our model client has a relation of One (client) 2 Many Beers.
But the beers have a relation of Many (beers) 2 One bar.
If you owned several bars, the relation between beer and bar is the same, the Many Beers 2 One Bar still works.
But if your Staff works in several places at the same time, the relation can be Many 2 Many, as each staff member, works on several bars, and there is not a fixed relation limiting how many staff work in each bar, or how many bars each person can work on.

id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink access_clientes_clientes,clientes.pc_clientes,model_clientes_pc_clientes,base.group_user,1,1,1,1 This is what my security file looks like, also, deleted the second relationship, thanks!

You need one access rule for each model.
Also try to remove or comment the field that is giving you an error from the xml template, to check if that is the only issue, you have in your code.

The issue arises because Odoo does not support accessing related fields in views using the dot notation <field name="pl_cliente_id.xfax"/>. Instead, you need to define a related field in your model and reference that related field in your view.
1. Define a Related Field in Your Model
In your model clientes.pc_clientes, create a related field that points to xfax from the pl_cliente_id model (clientes.pl_clientes):
class PcClientes(models.Model):
    _name = 'clientes.pc_clientes'
    _description = 'Clientes PC'
    _table = 'pc_clientes'
    _auto = False  # Odoo won't create this table automatically
    
    # Fields
    xempgen_id = fields.Char(string='EmpGen ID', required=True)
    xcliente_id = fields.Char(string='Cliente ID', required=True)
    xnomabrev = fields.Char(string='Nombre Abreviado')
    xnombre = fields.Char(string='Nombre', required=True)
    
    # Relational Field
    pl_cliente_id = fields.Many2one(
        'clientes.pl_clientes',
        string="PL Cliente",
        ondelete='cascade',
        required=True
    )
    
    # Related Field
    pl_cliente_xfax = fields.Char(
        related='pl_cliente_id.xfax', 
        string='Fax from PL Clientes'
    )

2. Reference the Related Field in the View
Once the related field is defined, you can reference it directly in the view:
<record id="clientes_list_view" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">clientes.list.view</field>
    <field name="model">clientes.pc_clientes</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <list>
            <field name="xempgen_id"/>
            <field name="xcliente_id"/>
            <field name="xnomabrev"/>
            <field name="xnombre"/>
            <field name="pl_cliente_xfax"/>
        </list>
    </field>
</record>


In any view of odoo, you cannot add field like  this, instead you can create a new field in python and add it
xfax = fields.Char(
    related='pl_cliente_id.xfax', 
    string='Fax from PL Clientes'
)

<record id="clientes_list_view" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">clientes.list.view</field>
    <field name="model">clientes.pc_clientes</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
      <list>
        <field name="xempgen_id"/>
        <field name="xcliente_id"/>
        <field name="xnomabrev"/>
        <field name="xnombre"/>
        <field name="xfax"/>
      </list>
    </field>
  </record>

Use “xfax” in both the views
